# Save a Connection in CSV File

Tags: sql-server, excel, csv

I have a connection to SQL Server in my .xlsx workbook.  Anytime I save it as a .csv it looses the connection.  Am I doing this process incorrectly, or is it not possible to save a connection in a .csv file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An xlsx file is really a zip file containing a number of different files/data that together make up what you see as a spreadsheet.  When you save as an xlsx file your connection info gets stored off into one of those secondary files.

When you save as a csv, however, only the data in your spreadsheet gets saved in that format.  All other metadata, including connection info, is not written to the csv.

So, no, you can't save a connection in a csv.

Comment: I was un-aware of how that worked.  Thank you for the precise explanation.